# RabbitVCS SSH Connection Failed

Tags: ssh, svn, fedora-16, rabbitvcs

I have installed RabbitVCS on Fedora16 64bit. When I try to checkout I get the following error

> To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from
>   'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
>   Network connection closed unexpectedly

Whereas I can successfully checkout using commandline SVN client provided by the subversion package.

So, how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rabbitvcs/DDfpuCwprnw) answers the issue, I have the same problem on my Linux system:

> This has been a long standing problem with PySVN (the Python bindings
>   we use under the hood for SVN work).
>
> See:
>   http://pysvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1335&dsMessageId=2621231
>
> Unfortunately, unless someone comes up with a solution, it looks like
>   you'll need to configure SVN+SSH to use keys instead of passphrases.

Sounds like a known issue they haven't resolved yet.